# Exception after settings UICollectionView with autosizing cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I carefully followed that [exemple](https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2) to transform my collectionView to use dynamic height while using Nibs.

After setting the **estimatedItemSize** in `viewDidLoad` here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    }
}
```

**I get this exception:**

```
2017-09-14 16:03:06.686930-0400 ClientCenterApp[404:48958] *** Assertion failure in -[_UIFlowLayoutSection computeLayoutInRect:forSection:invalidating:invalidationContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.7.47/UIFlowLayoutSupport.m:823
2017-09-14 16:03:06.689177-0400 ClientCenterApp[404:48958] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout internal error'
```

Anyone has an idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This this fixed my issues:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```